# On mobile/iOS views, is there a way to prevent my popup from being taller than my page?

Tags: css, jquery-plugins, responsive-design, magnific-popup

On my client’s site I’m using [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) to show the license agreement for their product when a “show agreement” link is clicked. So I’m using the inline type for a big long block of text. It works perfectly on the desktop. But it gets **all messed up at the bottom on mobile**.

If I understand correctly, at desktop views Magnific Popup sets `<html>` to `overflow: hidden` and the *popup* to `position: fixed`. At mobile views it *doesn’t* do this.

This would be fine, except for that my popup is so tall that it exceeds the height of my page. This means that it starts looking broken at the bottom.

[image: screenshot of overflow problem on iOS - iPhone]

I’d love to make it work on mobile/iOS as it does on desktop, but I’m starting to doubt that this is even possible. If anyone has any ideas I'd love to hear ‘em. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into applying specific styling for mobile devices using @media? Use this link as an example, http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I actually wasn't having trouble applying rules to different devices/widths… My problem was that I didn't know a good rule to apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `max-height: 100%, overflow-y: scroll` on the popup. This way the biggest it can be is the size of the viewport, but users can scroll within it.

Comment: Woohoo! It worked, good thinking! The only thing I added to that was `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to make it smooth. Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem, glad it worked and good thinking on the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`

Answer (score 0):

for `Magnific Popup - v1.1.0 - 2016-02-20` what worked for me was

```
.mfp-bg,
body.mfp-zoom-out-cur {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

`mfp-bg` is the background that can get larger than viewport and and allow scrolling